# Valor duplicado no banco ao inserir novo usuarios com uma Role já usada (Spring-Security)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa-2.0, spring-security

Olá

Estou criando uma aplicação web simples com SpringMVC e Spring Security. Fiz a classe Usuario e Roles da seguinte forma:

```
@Entity
public class Usuario implements UserDetails {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  private String username;

  private String password;
  private String nome;

  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();

...
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  private String role;
  private String name;

...
}
```

Estou deixando o Hibernate criar as tabelas automaticamente. O código gerado pelo Hibernate de criação da tabela é este:

```
Hibernate: create table Usuario (username varchar(255) not null, nome varchar(255), password varchar(255), primary key (username))
Hibernate: create table Usuario_Role (Usuario_username varchar(255) not null, roles_role varchar(255) not null)
Hibernate: alter table Usuario_Role add constraint UK_9ljdlf4fugq6jh14x7obwpi37 unique (roles_role)
Hibernate: alter table Usuario_Role add constraint FKb32xr1fddmr4pxdxuj5u14f56 foreign key (roles_role) references Role (role)
Hibernate: alter table Usuario_Role add constraint FKm7abqk7krlrd3bb61ecux2fnx foreign key (Usuario_username) references Usuario (username)
```

Adicionei 3 Roles no banco e no cadastro do usuário elas são exibidas e a pessoa pode selecionar quais as permissões daquele usuário. Quando eu adiciono um usuário e seleciono uma Role que não foi usada funciona normalmente, porem, quando seleciono uma que está sendo usada por outro usuário, da erro de duplicidade na tabela 'usuario_role' (Esta tabela está sendo criada automaticamente pelo Hibernate pela anotação @OneToMany). Mesmo se eu tentar inserir o usuário na mão pelo banco da o mesmo erro, então acho que é um problema seja criação das tabelas pois nem o "roles_role" nem o "Usuario_username" devem ser unicos na tabela, mas não sei o que fazer para corrigir.

Testes feito no banco:

```
mysql> show tables;
+-----------------+
| Tables_in_kmcdb |
+-----------------+
| atendimento     |
| role            |
| usuario         |
| usuario_role    |
+-----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from role;
+------------+---------------+
| role       | name          |
+------------+---------------+
| ROLE_ADMIN | Administrador |
| ROLE_SUP   | Supervisor    |
| ROLE_TEC   | Técnico      |
+------------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into usuario(username, nome, password) value('admin','admin','admin');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> insert into usuario(username, nome, password) value('fillipe','fillipe','fillipe');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into usuario_role(usuario_username, roles_role) value('admin','ROLE_ADMIN');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> insert into usuario_role(usuario_username, roles_role) value('fillipe','ROLE_SUP');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into usuario_role(usuario_username, roles_role) value('fillipe','ROLE_TEC');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from usuario_role;
+------------------+------------+
| Usuario_username | roles_role |
+------------------+------------+
| admin            | ROLE_ADMIN |
| fillipe          | ROLE_SUP   |
| fillipe          | ROLE_TEC   |
+------------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into usuario_role(usuario_username, roles_role) value('fillipe','ROLE_ADMIN');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'ROLE_ADMIN' for key 'UK_9ljdlf4fugq6jh14x7obwpi37'
mysql> insert into usuario_role(usuario_username, roles_role) value('admin','ROLE_SUP');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'ROLE_SUP' for key 'UK_9ljdlf4fugq6jh14x7obwpi37'
```

O que preciso modificar para conseguir inserir um novo usuário com uma role que já está sendo usada?

Obrigado

Comment: Você tem esta UK: `UK_9ljdlf4fugq6jh14x7obwpi37`. Ela é apenas para o campo `roles_role`, talvez seja melhor assim: `... unique (usuario_username, roles_role)`. Seu modelo de dados pode ser melhorado, mas alterar a UK já irá funcionar, creio eu.

Comment: Olá @bruno..
com a sua dica eu consegui raciocinar um pouco e mudei a relação para @ManyToMany.. Agora está funcionando normalmente..
Mas teria alguma forma de deixar a relação @OneToMany  o relacionamento ficar  `unique (usuario_username, roles_role)` como você disse?

Comment: A relação deveria ManyToMany mesmo. OneToMany seria se as roles fossem de apenas um usuário. Por exemplo: Tabela pessoa e telefone, teria um atributo telefone em pessoa anotado com OneToMany, uma pessoa tem vários telefones, mas o telefone só pertence a uma pessoa.

Comment: Entendi @Matheus.. vlw mesmo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver alterando a anotação no usuário para @ManyToMany

Como muito bem explicado acima pelo Matheus,

> OneToMany seria se as roles fossem de apenas um usuário. Por exemplo: Tabela pessoa e telefone, teria um atributo telefone em pessoa anotado com OneToMany, uma pessoa tem vários telefones, mas o telefone só pertence a uma pessoa. – Matheus Silva

Comment: Embora seja uma resposta OK (pois é a solução que encontrou), podia explicar como a alteração resolveu o problema?

Comment: @renan, o Matheus já tinha dado uma explicação muito boa na resposta da minha pergunta principal. Adicionei no corpo da resposta.